# Ubuntu 20.04 apt autoremove error: dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.4.0-56-generic (--remove):

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade, dpkg

The below error is stopping me from installing updates in my Ubuntu 20.04. It happens when I run `sudo apt autoremove`. I have also tried `sudo apt update/upgrade` with similar result. Help appriciated. Thanks

```
Removing linux-image-5.4.0-56-generic (5.4.0-56.62) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-56-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
/etc/grub.d/10_linux: 48: tr: not found
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-58-generic
/etc/grub.d/10_linux: 1: tr: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.4.0-56-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.4.0-56-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.4.0-56-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Uh oh: `/etc/grub.d/10_linux: 48: tr: not found` is serious. The `tr` application is provided by the `coreutils` package. Do you have any idea why core utilities are missing from your system? Is there other damage?

Comment: No idea. There is nothing else damaged as far as I can tell

Comment: Were it my system, I would back up my data and reinstall Ubuntu. When files vanish, there must be a reason or cause...and it's rarely good. However, if you want to try to fix it, reinstall the package: `sudo apt install --reinstall coreutils`